# Regexp to match snmp Oid by index

Tags: regex, bash, snmp

After performing 
`snmpwalk -v 2c -c public hostname 1.3.6.1.2.1.17.7.1.2.2.1.2` command I have the following output:

```
SNMPv2-SMI::mib-2.17.7.1.2.2.1.2.1.0.15.61.132.159.255 = INTEGER: 0
SNMPv2-SMI::mib-2.17.7.1.2.2.1.2.1.0.192.159.134.194.92 = INTEGER: 1
SNMPv2-SMI::mib-2.17.7.1.2.2.1.2.2.0.21.242.169.11.194 = INTEGER: 23
```

I need to add regexp by finding Oid by ifIndexes. For example ifIndex'es 0 and 23 I should have following output:

```
2.17.7.1.2.2.1.2.1.0.15.61.132.159.255
2.17.7.1.2.2.1.2.2.0.21.242.169.11.194
```

Comment: post your attempts...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Append this to your command with GNU grep:

```
| grep -Po -- '-\K[^-]*(?= = INTEGER: '"23"'$)'
```

Output:

```
2.17.7.1.2.2.1.2.2.0.21.242.169.11.194
```

Feel free to replace 23 by a variable.

Comment: Thanks. But how can I grep by multiple ifIndex'es. When I add more them more to expression my output is incorrect | grep -Po -- '-\K[^-]*(?= = INTEGER: '"0"\|"23"'$)'

Comment: Replace in my answer `23` by `(0|23)`.